# Getting error in a socket.io chat client on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, socket.io, ejs

I have uploaded a node.js, express chat app to Heroku, but it does not work.

Here is my log:

```
2017-03-12T15:55:42.109224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=socializechat.herokuapp.com request_id=d9a5ae24-a977-4c7e-83ff-e0e1dc989936 fwd="47.15.1.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Do you have any heroku logs?

Comment: 2017-03-12T15:55:42.109224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=socializechat.herokuapp.com request_id=d9a5ae24-a977-4c7e-83ff-e0e1dc989936 fwd="47.15.1.56" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Uh sorry for asking for something already showed. Have you tried `heroku restart`?